# Get MySQL data inside jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have list of user and I want to open each user detail in jQuery UI Popup. I write whole code but I'm confused how to pass each user ID to the dialog. Below is my code,

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog" title="User Detail">
  <p><?php $userID = $_GET[userID]; ?></p>
</div>

<a id="opener" href="#?userID=1">User 1</a>
<a id="opener" href="#?userID=2">User 2</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false
    });
    jQuery( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start IDs must be unique so I changed your opener ID into a class.

Then you may want to look at this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false
    });
    jQuery( ".opener" ).click(function() {
        jQuery("#dialog p").text(jQuery(this).attr("href").substring(jQuery(this).attr("href").indexOf('=') +1));
    jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
});
```

In short, you build your dialog and then you display it.

### And the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NZKw/)

Comment: it show the clickable data inside dialog. I want just to pass user ID. `text(jQuery(this).text()` this show the actual text which I click

Comment: when I click User 1, it should simple pass 1 in dialog box

Answer (score 0):

To start, you cannot reuse an ID for a DOM element, so the selector you're using will only work for the first instance of the link with id="opener".

When you open the dialog, jQuery is simply showing an element on the current page which already exists and is not making a request to that or a new page.  $_GET is a server-side super global and is only displayed when the page loads.

What you need to do is:

1. use "opener" as a class instead of an id
2. override the dialog's open
3. function to accept an additional parameter append that parameter to
   your dialog markup

You can accomplish this with the following code which grabs the user id from the href attribute:

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="User Detail">
  <p></p>
</div>

<a class="opener" href="#?userID=1">User 1</a>
<a class="opener" href="#?userID=2">User 2</a>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        open: function (event, ui) {
          var id = $(this).data('id');
          $('#dialog p').text(id);
        }
    });
    jQuery( ".opener" ).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('href').split('=')[1]; // grab id
        jQuery( "#dialog" ).data('id', id).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

The PHP to generate each link would look something like this:

```
$users = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'User 1',
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'User 2',
  )
);

foreach ($users as $user) {
  print "<a class=\"opener\" href=\"#?userID=$user[id]\">$user[name]</a>";
}
```

*note I was lazy on that last one and escaped the quotes within the printed string

Comment: how I will pass ID here `var id = $(this).attr('href').split('=')[1];`? do i need to put this jquery inside my php loop so for each record i have separate userID

Comment: I've updated my post to include a code sample for generating the links for each user in php.

Comment: Sorry but I think you didn't understand what i ask. I know how to generate user links with their ID's. i want to know how to grab user id in this line `split('=')[1]; // grab id` as you hard code 1 for test

Comment: That line of code grabs the href attribute from the link you clicked (example: "#?userId=1") and splits that value using "=" as the delimiter into an array ["#?userId", "1"] and grabs the second value of that array which is the userid.  The ID must already exist in the link that you generated.  When you call $('#dialog').data('id', id).dialog('open'); passes that variable to the dialog open method which then appends the variable in the dialog window.  If this doesn't make sense then I'm not sure what you are asking